# make return statement generic in pipe's transform method

Tags: javascript, angular, generics, typescript

I have created a pipe as shown below:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ 
    name: 'textFilter',
    pure: false
}) 
export class TextFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: any[], filter: string, properties: string[]): any {
        if (!collection || !filter) {
            return collection;
        }
        return collection.filter(obj => obj[properties[0]].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1
                                     || obj[properties[1]].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1);
    } 
}
```

I want to make return statement inside transform method more generic.

Look at the code, I have or condition there. I should be able to check for any number of properties instead of checking for obj[proeprties[0]]. I think I would be able to use for loop but how, I don't know. Can you please lead me to right direction.

**Update @JustAStudent:**

I have tried to implement as suggested in answer:

```
export class TextFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: any[], filter: string, properties: string[]): any {
        if (!collection || !filter) {
            return collection;
        }
        return collection.filter(obj => { returnVal(obj, filter, properties) });
    } 

    returnVal(obj: any, filter: string, properties: string[]) {
        let x: boolean;
        for(let i = 0; i <= properties.length - 1; i++) {
            x = x || (obj[properties[i]].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1)
        }
        return x;
    }

}
```

But I get error, when I try to call that function.

Comment: `return collection.filter(obj => properties.some(prop => obj[prop].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1));`

Comment: @yurzui this works fine. Thank you for taking time. Can you please post this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the test in an anonymous function and then use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example), after transforming the object properties you want to an array using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) function on the `properties`.

Example as runnable snippet:

```js
function pipe(collection, filter, properties) {
  filter = filter.toLocaleLowerCase();
  return collection.filter((obj) => {
    let values = properties.map((prop) => obj[prop]);
    return values.some((value) =>
      value.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1);
  });
}

console.log(
  pipe([{foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'},
        {foo: 'Test', bar: 'Bor'}], 'bo', ['bar'])
);
```

---

It is also possible to do this more directly, without using the mapping step in between, as [remarked](//stackoverflow.com/questions/43715171/make-return-statement-generic-in-pipes-transform-method/43715201?noredirect=1#comment74474098_43715171) by [yurzui](//stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui). This by applying the `some` function directly to the properties, and doing the lookup in that function. This could like like the following (again as runnable snippet).

```js
function pipe(collection, filter, properties) {
  filter = filter.toLocaleLowerCase();
  return collection.filter((obj) =>
    properties.some((prop) => obj[prop].
        toLocaleLowerCase().
        indexOf(filter) !== -1))
}

console.log(
  pipe([{foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'},
        {foo: 'Test', bar: 'Bor'}], 'bo', ['bar'])
);
```

Both of the above examples should be easy to substitute in your Angular code.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the update part in question?

Comment: I'm not near my computer now, will update the answer in a bit.

Comment: That answer is in fact slightly nicer than what I was going to propose, but I'll still update later, for completeness :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking time

Comment: @Vishal Updated. I also included yurzui's suggestion in the answer, just so that it appears in an answer and not only as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help